# How to take image as input in reactnative

Tags: react-native

Just the way as TextInput is used I need the user to upload an image in the field where it is asked for

For eg:  Upload Image: ___________ +
and user clicks the button to upload an image from gallery or take a photo from camera app of the phone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This library do exactly what you want

[React Image picker library](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker)

Comment: Is it not possible without a library

Comment: i could not find a way to do that in any of the official react native documentation i think the library is the only way as per my knowledge